# Remove specific words from a string (case insensitive)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms, replace

I get job contents that contain many word that I want to 'remove/replace' from the content. Example:

```
postcodes,Thank you , Click here
```

**Problem**

I have a list of words I want to remove from the content, but I am not sure how the words will appear within the content (upper case/lower case)...

So, how do I replace them?

Example - I want to replace:

```
associate degree in electronics or applicable equivalent
```

But in the content it can be :

```
associate Degree in electronics or applicable equivalent
Associate DEGREE in electronics or applicable equivalent
ASSOCIATE DEGREE IN ELECTRONICS or applicable equivalent
```

How can I replace them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?i)(associate DEGREE in ELECtronics)
```

Comment: Is it necessary to put | between the words?What if i have text like: hello & good morning friends!!!

Comment: @confusedMind, `|` is logical or. In other words this regex matches `associate` or `degree` or ...

Comment: Or , so suppose if i have in content associate degree in science , will it remove associate degree from this too as i do not want it?

Comment: @confusedMind, It will remove any word specified in regex. In this case: `associate`, `degree` and  `in`.

Comment: Nope that will be problem as in my job content there will be many place where the  word "in" should be like, job is in , or bring your degrees. So doing this will make other things useless.. I was hoping to only replace this like in c#  string.replace function  but with possibility of all small/big caps..

Comment: What if i only put "associate degree in electronics or applicable equivalent" ? Will it work as i want it? Also i am assuming the b and (?i) are to handle the combinations for the letters small\big caps?

Comment: @confusedMind, `\b` - is word boundary, `(?i)` -- turns on ignore case option.

Comment: The pattern does not work for me with boundary.This does  string pattern = "(?i)(associate DEGREE in ELECtronics)"; please update your answer so i can mark it..

Comment: Thank's a lot for the help! Really appreciated.

Comment: A issue in this approach : supose i have in the remover list FL  , and the string if Florist and Flower  , and its making the string orist and ower which is wrong because it should match full text only how can i do that?

Comment: @confusedMind, Use `\b`, e.g.: `\bFL\b`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Regex one possible solution will be:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(?i)(associate\s+degree\s+in\s+electronics\s+or\s+applicable\s+equivalent)", String.Empty);
```

You can use the same patter but create a Regex object, so you can provide a RegexOptions like:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?i)(associate\s+degree\s+in\s+electronics\s+or\s+applicable\s+equivalent)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

and later on you can use it as:

```
r.Replace(input, String.Empty);
```

Note: using a concrete Regex object gives you advantage of more flexible Replacement strategies, like MatchEvaluator, number of replacements as a count, etc...

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer but i just got help a few mins ago :).